# Model is binding with same level of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have a problem. In angular app I have three levels of ng-repeat and two checkboxes like:

```
<div ng-repeat="(ctIndex, ct) in cts">   
  <div ng-repeat="job in ct track by $index"> 
     <input type="checkbox" id="job{{ctIndex}}_{{$index}}" data-ng-change="checkJob(ctIndex, $index)" name="job{{ctIndex}}_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="job.selected">
     <div ng-repeat="(tId, task) in cs">
        <input type="checkbox" id="taskChecked{{ctIndex}}_{{$index}}_{{tId}}" data-ng-change="checkTask(ctIndex, $index, tId)" name="task{{ctIndex}}_{{$index}}_{{tId}}" data-ng-model="task.selected">
     </div>   
   </div> 
</div>
```

When **job.selected** and **task.selected** are in checked status also are checked checkboxes and model of its counterparts in another **ng-repeats**.
If I use **ng-checked** without **ng-model**, selected vars doesn't change.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for this ? thanks

Comment: In a fiddle example I haven't problem. I don't undestand it...

Comment: I use ECMAScript 6 and Gulp-babel 6.1.2, Babel preset-es2015 6.9.0 and gul ng-annotate 2.0.0 (inter alia), Angular 1.5.8...